# Powershell append line to variable in for loop

Tags: powershell

I have a foreach loop and use the write-host cmdlet to write to the console.
I now wish to write the lines into a variable that will store all of the result from the loop.
What is the cmdlet/syntax for this?

Comment: Post your actual code... Help us to help you!

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here and without even seeing the code say that you need to first not use Write-Host.

Comment: I know write host is incorrect I was just using this to watch the output on screen. However i need to simply change this rather than writing to host append a new line into a variable that will be fully populated

Comment: @meeeeeeeeee Do you want each line appended to a single string or do you want an array variable where every line is an element in the array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are couple of ways to do this. Putting the lines in a single string:

```
$lines = ''
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
{
    $lines += "The current value of i is $i`n"
}
$lines
```

Or as an array of strings where each line is a different element in the array:

```
$lines = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
{
    $lines += "The current value of i is $i"
}
$lines
```